# GPO StartLayout Never Applies

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I have not had any success deploying a StartLayout via GPO. Regardless of all I have tried, the pinned Start Menu icons remain the same.

After much research to avoid many common issues, I have simplified the creation and deployment of a Start Layout to the following:

**Notes:**

- Clients run Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB, Version 1607 (Build 14393.2273)
- I am logged in as a domain user: able to create and modify GPOs and a member of Administrators on the clients
- All other settings within this GPO apply correctly

**Part 1: Create custom StartLayout**

1. Unpin all icons from Start Menu
2. Pin **Windows Accessories\Paint** and **Windows Accessories\Notepad**
3. Set name of pinned group to **MyGroup**
4. Open **PowerShell**
5. Run `Export-StartLayout C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyGroup.bin` and confirm no errors displayed
6. Unpin all icons from Start Menu
7. Pin **Windows Accessories\Character Map**

**Part 2: Modify GPO**

1. Open **Administrative Tools\Group Policy Management**
2. Right click on existing GPO and click **Edit...**
3. Navigate to **Computer Configuration, Policies, Administrative Templates, Start Menu and Taskbar**
4. Double-click on **Start Layout**
5. Set to **Enabled**
6. Set **Start Layout** to **C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyGroup.bin**
7. Click **OK**
8. Close **Group Policy Management Editor** to save GPO

**Part 3: Apply GPO to client**

1. Open **Command Prompt** as administrator
2. Run **gpupdate /force** and confirm no errors displayed
3. Reboot and login

**Observations:**

- The only pinned icon is still **Character Map**, not **Paint** and **Notepad**
- I cannot unpin **Character Map**, pin other apps, or change a pin group name
- The following registry value is now set:

  - Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\
  - Name: StartLayoutFile
  - Value: C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyGroup.bin

**MyGroup.bin** (unmodified from earlier `Export-StartLayout`)

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
        <start:Group Name="MyGroup" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Paint.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

What am I doing wrong? What else can I try?

---

**EDIT: Follow up notes**

- Naming the file `MyGroup.xml` does not work either. Someone online suggested trying `.bin`

Comment: I guess GPO requires an XML file. You could try to export the Start Layout file using `.xml` for the filename extension.

Comment: @krisFR I tried the same procedure with `MyGroup.xml`, same behavior. A post online suggested trying `.bin`.

Comment: Perhaps you just omitted the obvious but did you link the GPO to your OU and add your user/computer group to the GPO? I don’t see that in your steps.

Answer (score 1):

The changes you're making are to the default profile, and as such will only apply to new accounts.  You'll need to delete your profile and log in again in order for the new StartLayout to apply to your account.

There's a fair amount of information here: https://www.joseespitia.com/2016/06/27/customized-a-windows-10-start-layout/

Answer (score 0):

Update the time stamp on your file

(ls ).LastWriteTime = Get-Date

Example:
(ls c:\defaultstartlayout.xml).LastWriteTime = Get-Date